# Stretching GridView

Tags: android, gridview

Im having a problem in stretching my GridView to fit Display-Width. Any one knows how so solve the problem? I want the GridView to occupy the whole width including the blue marked field (see pic below)

```
<TableRow>
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/timeBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"
    />  

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/points"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFE7BA"
        android:textSize="18px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    />
</TableRow>

<TableRow 
android:layout_weight="1" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
      android:text="KANJI"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:background="#aa0000"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_weight="2"
      />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" 
        />
</TableRow>
```

SCREENSHOT: http://i53.tinypic.com/2poy136.jpg

Comment: A GridView is not a GridLayout. Please change your question title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `layout_width` defined for your nested `GridView` so that its container knows how much space it needs:

```
<TableRow>
    <!-- added the line android:layout_width="fill_parent" -->
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
</TableRow>
```

You should also provide a layout_height to avoid any unexpected behavior.